# how to preserve objects across pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, report

let me start with that i am pretty new to c# 
currently i have to work on creating reports with a reporting tool called Stimulsoft

i wrote the following class

```
 public class HReports
{

    private Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner designer = new Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner(); //the designer
    private Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport(); //report
    //other fields


    public HReports(// params)
    {          
     this.designer.PreInit += new Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner.StiPreInitEventHandler(designer_PreInit); //registers the preinit event
    }


    private void attachData()
    {
     //load data from the database and add it to the report
    }


    public void showReport()
    {
            attachData();
            System.Web.UI.Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
            page.Controls.Add(designer); //add Stiwebdesigner to the page
            designer.Design(report); //opens a new page with the designer    
    }
    protected void designer_GetPreviewDataSet(object sender, Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner.StiPreviewDataSetEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PreviewDataSet = ds; // event that sets the preview dataset
    }
    protected void designer_PreInit(object sender, Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner.StiPreInitEventArgs e)
    {
        this.designer.GetPreviewDataSet += new Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiWebDesigner.StiPreviewDataSetEventHandler(designer_GetPreviewDataSet); // register the getpreview dataset 
    }

}
```

my problem is that when "designer.Design(report)" is called stiwebdesigner opens a new page with the designer reloads the page and displays a blank page because (i assume because the object was created on the original page and the object gets lost during the loading of the page)

how do a make the object available on the newly loaded page?
i have read something about serialization and the viewstate of asp pages that might have something to do with it, but i have to idea where to start

thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) variables ..

*ASP.NET session state* enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates *ASP.NET* pages in a *Web application*.

```
MyType myObject = (MyType)Session["MyObject"];

Session["MyObject"] = myObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use Server.Transfer ...but will prefer to go with Akram Shahda's answer using Session Variable.